# Write layers to spatial database using for loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, gis, r-sf

I would like to subset a spatial data frame and write the subsets to layers in a geodatabase in an automated fashion. I'm aware that `for` loops are neither the most elegant nor fastest way to achieve this goal, but for my purposes it will suffice. Here's an example using the `breweries` data set:

```
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

BR = breweries %>% 
  mutate(group = ifelse(zipcode >= 95000, "a", "b"))

for(i in unique(BR$group)) {

  dat = BR %>%
  filter(group == "i")
  st_write(dat, paste0(getwd(), "/testdatabase.gpkg"), paste0("testlayer_",i))

}

head(st_read(paste0(getwd(), "/testdatabase.gpkg"),"testlayer_a"))
```

Unfortunately, the resulting layers are empty although column names are written. Any suggestions?

Comment: The filter statement should probably be `filter(group == i)`, i.e. use the *variable* `i` and not the literal string `"i"`: That would explain why you get no data, because nothing passes through the filter statement (there is no group "i", only "a" and "b")

Comment: I really could have noticed that myself... Thanks for pointing it out!